# How to fetch dynamical XML data from a URL

Tags: php, xml

I am working on PHP and XML. I am sending some values like `origin,Destination,Journeydate,Returndate` to a particular URL. As a result according to my Values some XML data is generating in that URL. Now i want to fetch that generated result(XML Data) and print on my page.

I have tried the below code for printing the data of a URL

```
$url="your url";

$xmlinfo = simplexml_load_file($url);

print_r($xmlinfo);
```

It is not working.

I think it will work for the URL's which will contain Static XML data.

But here i want to send some values to a url. There the result will generate and then i want to get that generated result.

Here is the code how i am sending the values to URL

```
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
        <script language="Javascript">
        function submit_search()
        {       
            window.document.forms[0].action="URL";      
            window.document.forms[0].submit();
        }
        </script>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
        <form method="post">
            XML Request:    
            <input type="text" name="xmlRequest" id="fromcity" 
value="<AvailRequest>
     <Trip>ONE</Trip>
     <Origin>BOM</Origin>  
     <Destination>JFK</Destination>  
     <DepartDate>2013-05-01</DepartDate>  
     <ReturnDate>2013-05-05</ReturnDate>  
     <AdultPax>1</AdultPax>  
     <ChildPax>0</ChildPax>  
     <InfantPax>0</InfantPax>  
     <Currency>INR</Currency>  
     <PreferredClass>E</PreferredClass>  
     <Eticket>true</Eticket> 
    </AvailRequest>" />

            <input type="button" name="SUBMIT" value="submit" onClick="submit_search();"/>

        </form>
        </BODY>
        </HTML>
```

Thanks in Advance,
Shoba

Comment: You can check if generated url is working/opening directly to browser than it will work in code too. I will suggest you to use `CURL` method.

Comment: @Rikesh I dont have any idea on CURL.

Comment: You can read up on CURL here: http://codular.com/curl-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$url = 'URL GOES HERE';

//You need to build the front-end to grab and build the xml
//eg: $input_xml = "<AvailRequest><Trip>" . $_POST['trip'] . "</Trip> ......";
$input_xml = "<AvailRequest>
    <Trip>ONE</Trip>
    <Origin>BOM</Origin>  
    <Destination>JFK</Destination>  
    <DepartDate>2013-05-01</DepartDate>  
    <ReturnDate>2013-05-05</ReturnDate>  
    <AdultPax>1</AdultPax>  
    <ChildPax>0</ChildPax>  
    <InfantPax>0</InfantPax>  
    <Currency>INR</Currency>  
    <PreferredClass>E</PreferredClass>  
    <Eticket>true</Eticket> 
</AvailRequest>";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "xmlRequest=" . $input_xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//convert the XML result into array
$array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);

print_r('<pre>');
print_r($array_data);
```

Comment: My question is where i want to integrate this in my Above Code..Please let me know 

Regards,
Shoba

Comment: The code I supplied is supposed to replace the php code that you gave above. I do not get your question.

Comment: No actually PHP code i have given above i tried it in a different file and in the place of URL I have given some URL which contains some static XML data. But now i want to place that code in the above HTML code. Means after clicking on submit then the PHP code should submit. SO i am asking you where to place that PHP code..

Regards,

Shoba

Comment: I am not sure to get it but I updated the code above, check it out and let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am working on a flight portal API. I am sending the XML request form my PC and the result(Dynimically) is coming in the a URL of different serever. I just want to get that result and print on my file. Hope now u undertood my question

Comment: The url that you use to get the XML data, does it take any parameter?
If yes which one(s)?

Comment: Yes it take the values like `From Ariport`,`To Airport`,`From Date`,`Return Date`,`No of passengers`

Comment: So I assume you want the user to select the:
- Airport From
- Airport To
- From Date
- To Date
And in return display the flight available from the XML webservice you have\ right?

Comment: Are you using POST or GET to pass the data to the XML webservice?

Comment: I am using POST method. I have giving the WHOLE code in the question. Once please go through the question again.

Comment: Last question, is the webservice available over SOAP?
If yes you should try to use SOAP, or at least post the WSDL of the service so helping you would be easier, I am suspecting the format you are sending the data into is not correct

Comment: Check the answer above I completely changed it.
Remember to add the correct URL

Comment: Yes i will Check it...And Let You Know...!

Comment: No problem, this is what stackoverflow is for :-)