# Ingram micro integration using PHP

Tags: php, api, integration

I am trying to post XML request to ingram micro url the code shown below

```
 <?php

$url = "https://newport.ingrammicro.com/mustang";

$post_string = '<BaseRateRequest>
<Version1.0></Version1.0>
<TransactionHeader>
  <CountryCode>FT</CountryCode> 
  <LoginID>username</LoginID> 
  <Password>password</Password> 
  <TransactionID>TESTAIC12356</TransactionID> 
  </TransactionHeader>
<BaseRateInformation>
  <BranchOrderNumber>4066000</BranchOrderNumber> 
  <PostalCode>L5R1V4</PostalCode> 
  <Suffix /> 
  </BaseRateInformation>
  </BaseRateRequest>';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "XML=".$post_string);

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
print_r($data);    
?>
```

But, I don't know how to request and response in XML. I am getting the error: `Invalid Inbound XML Document`.

What does that means and how to solve it ?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697422/send-xml-data-to-webservice-using-php-curl

Comment: The error probably comes from the <Version1.0></Version1.0> shouldn't it be <Version>1.0</Version> ??

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove "XML="

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
```

and probably also add the XML header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BaseRateRequest>
...
</BaseRateRequest>
```