# CURL post via PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

Hi i need to make a curl Request via PHP passing a XML by POST but I have no idea how to do that anyone have any idea ?

what i have right now

```
$xml = '<project>
            ...
            </project>';

    $url = 'http://login:token@localhost:8080/createItem?name=newjobname';
    $fields = array(
        'name' => urlencode('newjobname'),
    );

    $fields_string = 'name=newjobname';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xmlRequest=" . $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send XML data to webservice using php curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697422/send-xml-data-to-webservice-using-php-curl)

Comment: i tried that solution but i'm making the post to a Jenkins server and don't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the login from the $url and add this to your curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "login:token");
```

Comment: :)) you should not do this in weekends :)